# sslv3 bad certificate alert while securing apache server

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, apache2

For using `simpleSAMLphp` I am following this https://github.com/buckbeak99/Securing-Apache-Server step by step to secure my Apache server with a self-signed certificate. After completing all steps when I run this command `openssl s_server -cert server.pem -www access` I access my custom domain in port 4433 besides adding generated certificate to the browser as instructed in the repo. I get this alert in the terminal:

```
800B28E2297F0000:error:0A000412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate:
../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1584:SSL alert number 42
```

[image: log error shown]

Comment: *"besides adding generated certificate to the browser as instructed"* - unfortunately, you only claim that you've followed the instructions but it is unclear what you really did. The error means that the client does not trust your certificate, which suggests that it is not properly added to the client or that something was done wrong when generating the certificate or that you've used a different certificate in s_server ... . Without information on what you really did it is impossible to point to the exact cause of the error and how to solve it

Comment: @SteffenUllrich i have edited the screenshot. as you are saying i have done something wrong. But every single steps outcome was as expected. Except `openssl s_server -cert server.pem -www access` this command. This command should help to access the custom domain in port 4433 with https. but in terminal the above mentioned image error is shown.

Comment: *"But every single steps outcome was as expected."* - and based on the description it is also expected that the browser initially complains about an insecure certificate. This error message is just the result of the browser not trusting the certificate. It should no longer happen if the CA is **properly** added to the browser.

Comment: I have added the ca.crt file in the Authorities tab of Firefox view_certificate options. Restarted the browser same problem arose.

Comment: Do you get an error message in the browser when trying to access the page? If yes, what exactly does it say?

Comment: Browser shows "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead"

Comment: The browser should be able to show way more detail than this. Please look closer, like at the Advanced link etc.

Comment: In Advanced link it is showing 'mydomain uses an invalid security certificate.' And 'The certificate is not trusted because it is self-signed.'

Comment: Then the CA certificate is not properly installed in the browser or you are using a certificate for the server which was not issued by the CA you've imported as trusted.

Comment: how can I test the certificate issued by the CA?

Comment: `openssl verify -CAfile ca.pem server-cert.pem`

Comment: there is no ca.pem in my demoCA folder.

Comment: Please abstract away from the actual file names. You have a server certificate and you have a CA. You have this CA imported as trusted in your browser as you claim. That's what I mean with ca.pem. So replace the names with what you actually have for server and CA.

Comment: if I run `openssl verify -CAfile ca.crt server.crt` it shows ok in the terminal. I have ca.crt, ca.key for CA and for the server I have server.key, server.pem, server.crt in my demoCA folder.

Comment: And you can see exactly this CA in your browser configuration as a trusted CA?

Comment: Yes. I have imported this CA to the browser.

Comment: *"I have imported this CA to the browser. "* That's not what I have asked. Can you actually see it as imported as a trusted authority (not as server or person or your own certificate - but as CA)?

Comment: I have imported the generated ca.crt to the browser certificates authorities tab and checked as a trusted certificate. But I am afraid how to make trusted authority as CA.

Comment: In order to help with debugging: could you provide the actual files you are using (CA cert, server cert and server key - should hopefully not be sensitive, since they are only self-signed and you could regenerate them later again) and show a screenshot which shows how the certificate is imported into firefox?

Comment: You get all the files and screenshots here [link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1U6VQhHJuLTEuw0tOL0jj-ZQxz6VpmX4X?usp=sharing).

Comment: There is no key provided for the server certificate - but I cannot create a test server without it. The screenshot does not show that the specific CA is actually trusted - it shows only the steps you've used to import it. The CN of the CA should not be the hostname. The server certificate does not have any subject alternative names - which are required today.

Comment: I cannot upload all files to the drive. some files are not uploading. These steps are shown in the repo to import to the browser. I'm afraid how to add a subject alternative name to server certificate.